# How to append item to array in Spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark-sql

How can I append an item to an array in dataframe (spark 2.3)?

Here is an example with integers, but the real case is with struct.

Input:

```
+------+-------------+
|   key|     my_arr  |
+------+-------------+
|5     |[3,14]       |
|3     |[9,5.99]     |
+------+-------------+
```

output:

```
+-------------+
|     my_arr  |
+-------------+
|[3,14,5]     |
|[9,5.99,3]   |
+-------------+
```

Comment: DataFrames are immutable: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: @WalrustheCat - True that a dataframe is immutable, but dataframes may be transformed into new dataframes (the whole idea of building a transformation pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

you must create udf to add elements , with integer is easy but with struct is more
 complicate.

With integers de code is :

`

```
 val udfConcat = udf((key:Int,my_arr:WrappedArray[Int])=> my_arr:+key)
     df.withColumn("my_arr",udfConcat(col("key"), col("my_arr"))).drop("key").show()
```

`

With struct de code is :

`

```
val schemaTyped = new StructType()
      .add("name", StringType)
      .add("age", IntegerType)
    val schema = ArrayType(schemaTyped)
    val udfConcatStruct = udf((key: Row, my_arr: Seq[Row]) => my_arr :+ key, schema)
    df2.withColumn("my_arr", udfConcatStruct(col("key"), col("my_arr"))).drop("key").show(false)
```

`

When you create the udf , you must pass de schema of Array , in this example is array of element with names and ages.

Comment: Thanks :), I was trying to avoid using UDF that accepts 2 columns because bad performance, but I think I don't have a choice

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `Struct`:

Input:

```
df.show()
+---+--------+
|Key|My_Array|
+---+--------+
|  5|  [3,14]|
|  3|  [9,45]|
+---+--------+

df.withColumn("My_Array", struct($"My_Array.*", $"Key")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+
|Key|My_Array|
+---+--------+
|5  |[3,14,5]|
|3  |[9,45,3]|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution without UDF -  PYSPARK**

I was facing similar kind of problem & definitely did't wanted to use UDF because of performance degradation

```
spark_df.show(3,False)

    +---+-----------+
    |key|myarr      |
    +---+-----------+
    |5  |[3.0, 14.0]|
    |3  |[9.0, 5.99]|
    +---+-----------+
```

Output:

```
spark_df=spark_df.\
        withColumn("myarr",F.split(F.concat(F.concat_ws(",",F.col("myarr")),F.lit(",") ,F.col("key")),",\s*" ) )

spark_df.select("myarr").show(3,False)


    +------------+
    |myarr       |
    +------------+
    |[3.0,14.0,5]|
    |[9.0,5.99,3]|
    +------------+
```

Method Steps:

1. First convert ***Array*** Column into ***String*** using ***concat_ws*** method
2. Use ***concat*** function to merge required column ("key") with original column ("myarr")
3. Use ***split*** function to convert ***string*** column from above step back to ***Array***

Hope this helps.